# How does one test the SSL cert on a specific server while testing through a load balancer?

Tags: ssl, load-balancing, linode

I use Linode's NodeBalancer and would like to make sure each of the servers are terminating the SSL correctly.

Right now I'm waiting on DNS propagation to test placing an A record of the format of `server1.secure.domain.com` where the SSL is valid for `secure.domain.com`.

Is this the correct method or is there something better?

Comment: That clearly did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use the openssl tool directly

for example:

```
openssl s_client -connect www.google.com:443 | openssl x509 -text
```

This will show you the cert that google has. Run the tool against each of your machines. You can check the subject and the certificate itself against whatever you have purchased and see if it's right.